# ADB unauthorized, having trouble connecting

Tags: android, key

Yes, this has been asked before, but I'm asking it a little differently.

First, I have done quite a bit of research, but it appears I have not found what Im looking for yet.

So, in "/data/misc/adb" SHOULD be a file called "adb_keys".  My old ROM install has this file.  However, my new ROM does not.  The folder is empty.  Im trying to add this file back into my ROM (upon initial install/boot).

I have yet to find a place where this file is located, or even how its generated.

I have the Nexus 6P.  My NPF10C ROM has it working fine.  My new NPF26F ROM doesnt work.  It give me the unauthorized warning in the Windows terminal window.  Also, I never get the authorization popup window on the phone.

Any ideas what Im missing?

Comment: Have you enabled ADB mode from your new Nexus 6P phone?

Comment: Yes I did.  Ive never had a problem with this in all my years of ROM building.  Just not sure what got caught up this time...